# how to perform dynamic subtraction of a list of numbers with a specific value

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, mutablelist

My idea is to subtract each value from my list through the value of a variable, for example:

```
var subtraction = 250
var list = mutableListOf(300, 200, 100)
```

Then, using the **250** of the subtraction variable,
you can dynamically subtract each value of the item,
from the last to the first, so with that **250** the program should return: -> list(**300, 50**).
Where **250** is subtracted from item **100 (last item)** and then **"150"** remains from the value **"250"**,
and the remaining **150** is subtracted from **200** (second item) and remains **50**,
thus zeroing out the value of **"250"** and the program stop.
Getting **(300, 50)** -> **50** which comes from **200** (second item).
**As if I was going through my list of numbers, subtracting item by item through the value of a variable, from last to first.**

Comment: So what is the question exactly? Did you try to implement this and faced an issue?

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you [removed your code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75139856/3)?

Comment: I want to loop through my list of values, subtracting each value (item) from my list with a specific value.

Comment: excuse me. What I put as code wasn't exactly code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question still needs further clarification:

- What should be the output if `subtraction = 700`?
- What should be the output if `subtraction = 600`?
- What should be the output if `subtraction = 100`?

The following can be a starting point to solve your question:

```kotlin
fun subtraction() {
  var subtraction = 250
  var list = mutableListOf(300, 200, 100)
  // Loop the list in Reverse order
  for (number in list.indices.reversed()) {
    subtraction -= list[number] // Subtract the last number
    // If subtraction is greater than zero, continue and remove the last element
    if (subtraction > 0)
      list.removeAt(number)
    else {
      // It subtraction is less than or equal to zero, 
      // remove the last element, append the final subtraction result, 
      // and stop the loop
      list.removeAt(number)
      list.add(abs(subtraction))
      break
    }
  }
  // If the subtraction result is still positive after whole list has been processed, 
  // append it back to the list
  // if (subtraction > 0)
  //   list.add(subtraction)
  println(list)
}
```

**Output**

```
[300, 50]
```

Comment: Well, 700 is greater than all the numbers in the list, so it won't return anything.
If it is 600 it will return:
[0].
If it is 100 it will return:
[300, 200].
If it is 300 it will return:
[300]. The output of this code you submitted is the expected result. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, but as I understand it: OP wants to modify a list of numbers, subtracting a fixed amount from each, and removing those for which the result would be negative.

If so, it can be done very simply:

```
list.replaceAll{ it - subtraction }
list.removeIf{ it < 0 }
```

However, instead of mutating the existing list, it would probably be more common to create a new one:

```
val newList = list.map{ it - subtraction }.filter{ it >= 0 }
```

Or, if you need to avoid creating a temporary list:

```
val newList = list.mapNotNull{ (it - subtraction).takeIf{ it >= 0 } }
```

Comment: That's what I tried to explain !!

Comment: This code is not giving expected results...

Comment: @MarianoMuendane It works for me (as best I can understand what you're asking). Please give the input you're using, and the results you're expecting.

Comment: var subtraction = 250 |
var list = mutableListOf(300, 200,100) |

Exit by list = [300, 50]

Comment: @MarianoMuendane `var subtraction = 250` `var list = mutableListOf(300, 200,100)` `list.replaceAll{ it - subtraction }` `list.removeIf{ it < 0 }` `println(list)` gives me `[50]` as expected, in both IDEA and the REPL. I can't imagine what you're doing to get anything else.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with *foldRight* using a Pair as accumulator:

```
val list = listOf(300, 200, 100)
val subtraction = 250

val result = list
  .foldRight(subtraction to emptyList<Int>()) { item, (diff, list) ->
    when {
      diff > item -> diff - item to emptyList()
      else        -> 0           to listOf(item - diff) + list
    }
  }
  .second

println(result)   // Output: [300, 50]
```